# Modifying ng-show in a setTimeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller like so:-

```
appControllers.controller("TaskAddController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.task = {};
    $scope.messages = {};

    $scope.actions = {
        save : function() {
            $http.post("/ajax/tasks/save", $scope.task)
            .then(function() {
                $scope.messages.success = true;
                $scope.task = {};

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $scope.messages.success = false;
                }, 3000);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The view looks like so:-

```
<div data-ng-controller="TaskAddController">
    <div data-ng-show="messages.success">Task Added</div>
    <div>
        <input data-ng-model="task.title" type="text" placeholder="Title...."/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea data-ng-model="task.description" placeholder="Description..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input data-ng-click="actions.save()" type="submit" value="add"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is on the completion of the AJAX request I want to show the `div` containing Task Added, then after 3 seconds have it disappear The first part is working, e.g. the div appears when the AJAX request completes, but even though my setTimeout is definitely happening, the `div` is not disappearing.

Now from my research I thought it was because I need to get the Angular digest to fire. So I tried the following:-

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $scope.messages.success = false;
    $scope.apply();
}, 3000);
```

But that didn't seem to make a difference. What am I missing?

Comment: It's $scope.$apply()... and if you use $timeout() instead of setTimeout() and Angular will take care of that for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `$timeout`.

```
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.messages.success = false;
}, 3000);
```

**Note** : You need to inject `$timeout` in your controller.

Comment: Thank you sir. That works like a charm. Apparently I need to wait 8 minutes to mark it as the answer.